# using accesskey across the element in other iframe is not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, accessibility, access-keys

At chrome, I focus at "A" iframe. There is element setted accesskey attribute on other iframe. I can't use accesskey to focus on the element. This problem doesn't exist at IE,FF.

Is there some trick can solve this problem? my code is below:

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"  accesskey="b" name="some_name" value="">
    <iframe src="a.html"></iframe>
    <iframe src="b.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

**a.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"  accesskey="e" name="some_name" value="">
</body>
```

**b.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"  accesskey="t" name="some_name" value="">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be to do with what context the current focus is looking at. So if the user has not clicked inside the respective iframe then the access key will not work. One way to implement this would be to trigger a javascript keyevent, which forwards the key event into each of the iframes until it has met a corresponding access key attribute.